# I have a message

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual, computer-puzzle

I have an encoded message and I want you to find out what it is. For the answer to be accepted, you must clearly demonstrate and explain each step in the encoding process. The message contains four English words.

### ***Hello***

[image]

### ***World***

[image]

### ***Hello World***

[image]

### ***????***

[image]

### ***Transcription***

---

For your convenience, the following are the transcriptions of the information contained in the four images:

***First***

```
000011
100010
011110
001101
000111
001000
010110
010111
```

***Second***

```
000100
011100
010010
010110
000000
001111
010001
010000
```

***Third***

```
001010
100011
100000
000101
001011
100011
000010
100001
011001
000101
000110
010110
000100
011010
100010
001100
010100
```

***Fourth***

```
011001
001010
011010
001001
011101
000110
001010
011101
000011
011110
010111
010001
001110
001100
000101
000111
100001
000000
011010
000111
001100
100010
100000
```

Comment: Are the colors supposed to be black and white or are there more colors?

Comment: They are supposed to be black and white, and what concept is related to black and white?

Comment: Is this something to do with binary? That’s all I can think of.

Comment: Correct, the images represents digits of some number in a certain number system in binary, each column represents a digit. But you still need two more steps to get back the message though.

Comment: You need 1437812

Comment: I thought they are binary of ASCII Values, I was wrong.

Comment: @I'mNobody It turns out you are both right and wrong!

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

> The End is Nigh

Cipher:

> Encode the text as bytes using the ASCII character encoding, and represent the bytes as a string of hexadecimal digit pairs. Treat this string of digits as a single long hex numeral and change its radix from 16 to 36 to obtain a string of digits in base 36. Replace each digit with its value, encoded as binary, one line (image column) per digit.

Solve path:

> Treat each line (image column) in the transcription as a six-bit binary numeral. (The transcription saves us the trouble of noticing that the numerals are written upwards.) Notice that no line has a value greater than 35. Convert each line to a base 36 digit to form a base 36 numeral. Convert this numeral to all smaller radices, recognize the pattern of hex-encoded ASCII values on radix 16, and complete the solution.

[The solution is also available as a CyberChef recipe. (SPOILERS)](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Fork(%27%5C%5Cn%5C%5Cn%27,%27%5C%5Cn%5C%5Cn%27,false)Fork(%27%5C%5Cn%27,%27%27,false)From_Base(2)To_Base(36)Merge(false)From_Base(36)To_Base(16)From_Hex(%27Auto%27)&input=MDAwMDExCjEwMDAxMAowMTExMTAKMDAxMTAxCjAwMDExMQowMDEwMDAKMDEwMTEwCjAxMDExMQoKMDAwMTAwCjAxMTEwMAowMTAwMTAKMDEwMTEwCjAwMDAwMAowMDExMTEKMDEwMDAxCjAxMDAwMAoKMDAxMDEwCjEwMDAxMQoxMDAwMDAKMDAwMTAxCjAwMTAxMQoxMDAwMTEKMDAwMDEwCjEwMDAwMQowMTEwMDEKMDAwMTAxCjAwMDExMAowMTAxMTAKMDAwMTAwCjAxMTAxMAoxMDAwMTAKMDAxMTAwCjAxMDEwMAoKMDExMDAxCjAwMTAxMAowMTEwMTAKMDAxMDAxCjAxMTEwMQowMDAxMTAKMDAxMDEwCjAxMTEwMQowMDAwMTEKMDExMTEwCjAxMDExMQowMTAwMDEKMDAxMTEwCjAwMTEwMAowMDAxMDEKMDAwMTExCjEwMDAwMQowMDAwMDAKMDExMDEwCjAwMDExMQowMDExMDAKMTAwMDEwCjEwMDAwMA)